# How read latitude and longitude from C# app on laptop with built-in mobile broadband?

Tags: c#, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm writing a C# app that will run on tablets with mobile broadband built in.  I'm wanting to capture the latitude and longitude values from code.  Can anyone tell me how this can be done, please.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Please provide us with more information as this question is way too broad to be answered properly.

Comment: I'm wanting to get the lat/lon to pass to our database to see if it within a certain poly area that we have already defined using SQL Server geography data type.